# Genetical algorithms. How to find the optimal size of the population

Tags: c#, genetic-algorithm

How to find the optimal size of the population. In my task, each gene is a value of type int lying in a given range.

For example:

1. The chromosome consists of 2 genes.
2. The first gene maybe contains a int value in the range from 5 to 15
3. The second gene maybe contains a int value from 15 to 25.

The question. How to find the size of the initial population.

Comment: Could you please add your code so far?

Comment: Have you even tried to do this yourself or do you think we are just gonna write it for you?

Comment: Maybe this document will help you http://www.cameron.edu/~pdiaz-go/GAsPopMetric.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Usually optimal size is found iteratively through trial and error. You can write a simple algorithm to optimize population size, start for example with pop size of 100 and iterativly increase it by e.g. 50. For each step you need to run GA and calculate some measure that will assess population size, you can use one of these: maximum fitness, average fitness, time till convergence criteria is met. To increase accuracy you should repeat each step at least few times, after that calculate average in each step and draw chart from which you can choose optimal pop size or if it's not enough you can optimize closely peak doing the same thing near this pop size.

Depending on your problem the chart will look different. If it's just a positive slope curve, then you will have to choose on your own reasonable pop size. With too small pop size your GA will most likely loose diversity and perhaps fall to some local optimum. When it's too big then your GA will become simple random search algorithm.

Btw I hope this example is far from your real problem, because genetic algorithms are not the best choice for such small chromosomes.

Comment: Finding parameters of GA in general is optimization task. Task good for GA so, it can use metaevolution(another GA for GA optimization) for optimizing GA parameters. But this solution(except special cases) is too much energy and time for disputable result.